# Magento 2.3 translations (translate label) in the admin panel (backend)

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.3, localisation, translate, i18n

In Magento 1 I just added a translate.csv for my admin area.
How can I achieve this in Magento 2?
I just want to change the translations of a few things and add some missing translations. Can't I put a de_De.csv for the adminhtml area somewhere?

How to handle **translations for the admin** panel (backend).
Thanks

Comment: I tried your solution on Magento 2.2.9 but seems not working
I need to add **fr_FR.csv** translation for some extensions who are under /vendor/amasty/extension_name
so I had created directory structure under `/app/code/Amasty/Extension_name/i18n`
and uploaded **`fr_FR.csv`** file inside
... but translation doesn't work ! N.B : if i upload fr_FR.csv file under the `/vendor/...../i18n` it works but in this case each time I update the extension, it erease the translation file. Does someone find a solution for module translation ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

With your **custom module**, you can create an **i18n folder** and place your translation file inside.  The path should look like this:

> app\code\vendor\module\i18n\yourTranslationFile.csv
>   which in your case is `de_De.csv`

Comment: what would the path of the tranlsation file be if I want to change a label for the admin panel?

Comment: refer from this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html#m2devgde-xlate-languagepack

Answer (score 1):

[You can download code from here](https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-backend-theme)

Edit/Add CSV as per your Locale.
app/design/adminhtml/Shah/default/i18n

[image: Admin Text Translated]

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, translations file is saved in `/vendor/magento/<module-modulename>/i18n` folder.

For example, if you want to modify translation for word related to checkout module, it could be saved in `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/<locale-folder>` folder.

You can copy locale's csv file from `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n` folder to `app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n` directory.

Answer (score 0):

put translate file under theme not working for backend.

Need create a custom module, add  in module.xml, then add translation file under i18n folder (vendor/VENDOR/MODULE/i18n/en_NZ.csv, or app/code/.../i18n/en_NZ.csv).

**Double-check your account interface Locale set properly.**
e.g. en_NZ.csv work for English(New Zealand).

above solution not working for en_US, if need support this, then
**just create admin theme**, follow magento docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html

then add en_NZ.csv/en_US.csv under admin theme i18n folder.