# Magento 2 : change text "Refund Offline to Refund Store credit"

Tags: creditmemo

is their any way i can change this text of button ?

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/7867140?key=86b39c1af672331d41d7d7da1ae189af

its credit memo button

[image]

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate text via i18n as per your locale.
The file should be at app/design/adminhtml/Shah/default/i18n/en_US.csv

You can download code from [here.](https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-backend-theme)

OR

you can translate inline to enabling from admin. Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Translate Inline -> Enabled for Admin = Yes and you can translate manually.

OR

you can check [here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265297/magento-2-3-translations-translate-label-in-the-admin-panel-backend/336328#336328)

Comment: Hello, i have added "en_US" csv file in i18n folder in module root
with "Refund Offline","Refund Store Credit" text

Comment: but changes are not appearing

Comment: @devhs Copy your i18n folder and paster under adminhtml theme.
Like from this code https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-backend-theme 
app/design/adminhtml/Shah/default/i18n/en_US.csv
I am able to translate from admin theme https://prnt.sc/12glf8k

Comment: Hello, thanks for suggestion, unfortunately i can not create theme in website its not allowed to do so.
Is their any workaround we can use ?

Comment: Yes, you can translate inline to enabling from admin.
Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Translate Inline -> Enabled for Admin = Yes and you can translate manually.

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: Let me know If you face any issue or need help.

Comment: Sure, i will check soon & update here.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Hello, i have tried "Translate Inline" & it worked !
Though i am advised to implement (change text) using file in module.
So i have followed the way you told copied  "i18n"  folder from module-sales & added into module Vendor/Module/i18n/en_Us.csv
then i had executed di:compile & refreshed cache, still changes i made in i18n did not reflected.
I doubt if i am missing something, could you please share your thoughts on this ?
I appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123776/discussion-between-mital-shah-and-devhs).